# How to convert byte array to Base 64 string in unsigned way in java?

Tags: java, c#, base64

I am struggling to get the same Base64 string in both C# and Java

I want Java to treat bytes as unsigned ones when converting to Base64.

Here's my C# code

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long baseTimeStamp = 1501492600;
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(baseTimeStamp * 114);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] >> 2);
    }

    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    Console.WriteLine(base64);
}
```

In Java, I want to get the same Base64 for the same `long` value

Here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long myLong = 1501492600;

    byte[] bytes = longToBytes(myLong);

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length / 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = bytes[i];
        bytes[i] = bytes[bytes.length - i - 1];
        bytes[bytes.length - i - 1] = (byte) temp;

        bytes[i] = (byte)((bytes[i] >> 2));
    }

    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes));
}

private static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    buffer.putLong(x);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

I tried both the commented way, and the `DatatypeConverter` way, but I get different String values. Is there a standard JDK way, or should I write my own base64 method to treat bytes as unsigned ones?

Comment: Base64 does not care about "signed" or "unsigned". I guess the problem is that you are converting diffferent byte-arrays, so you might find the source of the problem in `longToBytes` - whatever that does.

Comment: Since `>>` in C# is logical shift, you need to do `bytes[i] = (byte)((bytes[i] & 0xff) >> 2)` in order to do the same with Java.

Comment: I tried that our, but it works only when I assign to an int, when I assign back to a byte, I lose the unsigned behavior again

Comment: Try adding  `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` before `buffer.putLong` and see if things improve....

Answer (score 1):

Base64 converts bits. It doesn't know or care about whether you think of the bytes as signed or unsigned. If you're getting different values, the problem is somewhere else.

However, since you're doing bit shifting, you need to use the zero-fill version `>>>` instead of the sign extend `>>`. That may be the source of your problem.

`DatatypeConverter` is still the easiest way to go.

Comment: you're right, the conversion is right, the problem lies in shifting, although there's no difference in my case between `>>` and `>>>`